# reading a .properties file stored in hdfs using java code

Tags: java, hadoop, workflow, oozie

i need to read .properties file which is available in the hdfs. i am using the below code but it throws a run time error.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);

    Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String appPath = "hdfs://clusterdb05.com:8020/user/cmahajan/" + version + "/apps/apps/";
    conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH,appPath);
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("hdfs://clusterdb05.com:8020/user/cmahajan/app.properties");
    ObjectInputStream f = new ObjectInputStream(fs.open(new Path("/user/cmahajan/app.properties")));
```

the run time error is :

```
LaunchJob.java:28: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class ObjectInputStream
location: class LaunchJob
    ObjectInputStream f = new ObjectInputStream(fs.open(new Path("/user/cmahajan/app.properties")));
    ^
LaunchJob.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ObjectInputStream
location: class LaunchJob
    ObjectInputStream f = new ObjectInputStream(fs.open(new Path("/user/cmahajan/app.properties")));
```

Comment: What is your complete code, including imports? It would appears that you are missing an `import java.io.ObjectInputStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use fully qualified name of class:

```
java.io.ObjectInputStream
```

OR

import the class using following line:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
```

Comment: this was missing in the code. but now it gives StreamCorruptedException at line : "ObjectInputStream f = new ObjectInputStream(fs.open(new Path("/user/cmahajan/app.properties")));". any known reason?

Comment: I may not know the exact reason but it means that the data you are reading is not formatted as expected. Refer this: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/StreamCorruptedException.shtml

Answer (score 2):

For loading properties file form hdfs:

1. make sure ur **core-site.xml**,**hdfs-site xml** file path
2. hdfs port no(it will available in **core-site.xml**)
3. replace key in **getProperty**.

   ```
          String CURRENCIES_DIM1 = null;
          String DATES_DIM2 = null; 
          Configuration conf = new Configuration();
           conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
           conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
           String filePath = "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/CurrencyCache.properties";
           Path path = new Path(filePath);
           FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
           try (FSDataInputStream currencyInputStream = fs.open(path)) {
               Properties currencyProp = new Properties();
               currencyProp.load(currencyInputStream);
               CURRENCIES_DIM1= currencyProp.getProperty("key");//getting the 'CURRENCIES_DIM' file path from properties file
               DATES_DIM2= currencyProp.getProperty("key");            //getting the 'DATES_DIM' file path from properties file

           } catch (IOException e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           fs.close();
   ```